# Awk all lines above matched parameter

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, ksh, aix

I have a file called test.out with the below lines in:

```
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9117025 Jan 21 05:22 shop4_0_Log0000331875.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    8897981 Jan 21 05:24 shop4_0_Log0000331876.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9325351 Jan 21 05:31 shop4_0_Log0000331877.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9645109 Jan 21 05:34 shop4_0_Log0000331878.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9950581 Jan 21 05:40 shop4_0_Log0000331879.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10655940 Jan 21 05:59 shop4_0_Log0000331880.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10832325 Jan 21 06:39 shop4_0_Log0000331881.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    8521443 Jan 21 07:42 shop4_0_Log0000331882.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10283566 Jan 21 08:02 shop4_0_Log0000331883.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10633957 Jan 21 08:51 shop4_0_Log0000331884.Z
```

I want to print all lines above grep value 331881 parameter:

My desired outcome must be like below:

```
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9117025 Jan 21 05:22 shop4_0_Log0000331875.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    8897981 Jan 21 05:24 shop4_0_Log0000331876.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9325351 Jan 21 05:31 shop4_0_Log0000331877.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9645109 Jan 21 05:34 shop4_0_Log0000331878.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9950581 Jan 21 05:40 shop4_0_Log0000331879.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10655940 Jan 21 05:59 shop4_0_Log0000331880.Z
```

Using the command below command I can specify how much lines above to print:

```
grep -n 331881 test.out | cut -d':' -f1 |  xargs  -n1 -I % awk "NR<=%+0 && NR>=%-1" test.out | sed '$d'
```

The above command will only print the specified amount of lines in this case 1 line, but I want to change the above to print all above the grepped line. I am struggling to find a solution to my problem or an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use awk directly:

```
awk '/331881/ { exit } 1' test.out
```

This will print all lines, but for a line matching `331881`, quit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are located in the directory that holds the listed files, using `zsh`:

```
ls -ld shop4_0_Log<331882->.Z
```

The `<331882->` is a `zsh`-specific glob that matches integers that are 331882 or larger.

With some other shell:

```sh
for name in shop4_0_Log*.Z; do
    number=${name#shop4_0_Log}
    number=${number%.Z}

    if [ "$number" -ge 331882 ]; then
        ls -ld "$name"
    fi
done
```

Here, we loop over the names that start with `shop4_0_Log` and end with `.Z`. For each such name, we pick out the integer part of the filename, and if it is 331882 or more we call `ls -ld` on the name.

If the leading zeros are causing the shell to interpret some of the numbers as octal (it doesn't in my tests), then use `10#$number` in the test to force the number to be interpreted as a decimal integer (this is supported by `ksh` and `bash` and some other shells).

Neither of these two variations relies on the presence of a text file that contains some `ls` output.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Answer (score 1):

Another good tool would be `sed`:

```
sed -n '/shop4_0_Log0000331881\.Z$/q;p' test.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `and` condition, remove the following code from your one liner:

```
&& NR>=%-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
j=`awk '/331881/{print NR}' file`

awk -v j="$j" '{a[++i]=$0}/331881/{for(x=NR-j;x<NR;x++)print a[x]}' file
```

output

```
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9117025 Jan 21 05:22 shop4_0_Log0000331875.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    8897981 Jan 21 05:24 shop4_0_Log0000331876.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9325351 Jan 21 05:31 shop4_0_Log0000331877.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9645109 Jan 21 05:34 shop4_0_Log0000331878.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix    9950581 Jan 21 05:40 shop4_0_Log0000331879.Z
-rw-rw----    1 informix informix   10655940 Jan 21 05:59 shop4_0_Log0000331880.Z
```